# QGIS automated export to image of multiple layersets

Tags: qgis, export, image

I have one project that contains layers in QGIS.
Every layer is a quarterly update of my fairway showing the fairwayprofile and aids-to-navigation of the whole of my administration area.

### My current workflow.

- Choose area of interest.
- make sure every layer has the same symbology
- selecting the first layer (say 2008-Q4)
- exporting it as a image on 300dpi JPEG
- selecting the next layer, export and repeat until all layers are exported
- make video to show the movement of my fairwayprofile.

example video: (still bit rough, work in progress)
https://vimeo.com/344980749

This is "do-able" cause on this detail I only have an update every quarter. But in high-detail I have hundreds of layers that i want to use for making a similar video. Is there a way to automate the process or does anybody have knowledge of a plugin?

(automate process: selecting layer, exporting layer, selecting layer, exporting layer, etc)